# Detect Content-Type/MIME Type of an S3 Object

Tags: node.js, http, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, react-native

I am sending a pre-signed URL, generated by my server using S3 SDK, to the client app. I can not decide in a first place if the URL will be used to upload either a MP4 video or a JPG image (so no Content-Type set in the pre-signed URL).

I will need to download that file later on the client (NodeJS - React Native).

Is there a way to determine the file format of the S3 Object (without being based on the filename) to then be able to view it with the proper tag (in this case, either `<img>` or `<video>`)?

Thanks a lot

Edit: I have just been thinking that maybe the client can set the content-type by itself when uploading? I am not sure if I will get an access denied by S3 since the Content-Type won't be defined in the pre-signed URL. This way I can know data type when downloading. Would that work? (Will try tomorrow though)

Comment: Maybe you could send the client two pre-signed URLs, one for MP4 and one for JPG, and let the client use the one's that's relevant to the content type?

Comment: I want as less choice as possible given to the client for safety purpose. Plus it's twice as much calls to AWS API, not sure on the limites and billing about this

Comment: Generating signed URLs is a local operation -- it does not involve any calls to the AWS API.  Signed URL generation is done on the machine that runs the code that creates the signed URL.

Comment: my bad; that would make sense actually. I still don't like the idea of giving the user 2 urls, in case he uses the bad one doing some hacking though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise setting the content-type on PUT. But, when using signed URLs you can override the content-type and content-disposition.

### [S3 RESTObjectGET API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html)

Example:

```
https://my.examplesite.com/some/path/file.jpg?response-content-type=image/jpeg&response-content-disposition=attachment;%20filename="coolcat.jpg"
```

Important Note: "Content-type" should precede "Content-Disposition" such as in the above example. Also these query string values are not included in the signature generation, they are added to the URL after the signature is generated.